# How to access key/value of the array in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

**How to access key/value of the array in Laravel 4 ?**

**CREATE**

```
echo Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'), 'S');
```

**SHOW**

```
{{{ $shirt->size or ''}}}
```

**RESULT**

It keep showing me **L**, but I want to Display as **Large**

Can anybody tell me how to do that, please ?

Comment: `$shirt->size['L']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{ Form::select('size', array('Large' => 'Large', 'Small' => 'Small'), 'Small') }}
```

While waiting for someone to help me with this question. I did the above code and it seem to do the trick as what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is *you can't*, or at least not in the way you're expecting. When an item is selected and posted back to you, all that is sent back is the *value* of the `<option>` element, not it's content.

Note that:

```
{{ Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'), 'S') }}
```

produces HTML a little like this:

```
<select name="size">
    <option value="L">Large</option>
    <option selected value="S">Small</option>
</select>
```

But the key-value pairing between "L" and "Large" etc. is now lost. It's used to create the HTML markup, but nothing more - it's not stored anywhere for you to access it directly through Laravel.

When your form is submitted and posted to wherever it's meant to be posted, your browser *only* sends the *value*, in this case "L". Laravel has no idea that "L" means "Large". You will need to have this information stored elsewhere, for example:

```
$sizes = array(
    'L' => 'Large',
    'S' => 'Small'
);
```

Then you could use (provided `$sizes` is passed to your `View`):

```
{{ Form::select('size', $sizes, 'S') }}
```

and retrive the value with `$sizes[$shirt->size]`.

If you want to be extra careful (as someone could edit the HTML to submit a value different from "L" or "S"), you can do something like

```
$size = (array_key_exists($shirt->size, $sizes) ? $sizes[$shirt->size] : '');
```

---

A second idea, as it looks like you have a `Shirt` model, would be to add the following to that class:

```
public $sizes = array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small');

public function getSizeAttribute($v) {
    return (array_key_exists($v, $this->sizes) ? $this->sizes[$v] : '');
}
```

Then `$shirt->size` will do exactly what you want and spit out "Large".